# How to make this C# code work in windows phone? BitmapData.Scan0

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have this C# snippet which works great, but I can't use it in Windows Phone because `System.Drawing.Imaging` is not supported. anyway.

```
    BitmapData bmpDat = bmp.LockBits(
        new Rectangle(
        0,0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height),
        ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);

    int result = Avi.AVIStreamWrite(writeCompressed ? compressedStream : StreamPointer,
        countFrames, 1, 
        bmpDat.Scan0, 
        (Int32)(bmpDat.Stride * bmpDat.Height), 
        0, 0, 0);
```

There is no `BitmapData` because of that, but I just want to `bmpData.Scan0` work, how can I solve this problem and produce `bmpData.Scan0` data?

about `Scan0` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.bitmapdata.scan0.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is mentioned [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/db69e70f-a631-4797-90a6-7ec2949811a6/bitmapdata-and-windows-phone-what-could-be-done?forum=silverlightwinphone):

> Hi. Use a [WriteableBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) instead (which can be constructed from a Bitmap object). It has a [Pixels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.pixels%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) property that allows access to the individual pixels as integer values (one byte each for RGBA).